# Getting lines from GL10 drawing images next to one another, solution?

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, bitmap, line

I have a background image I am drawing with open gl 1.0 es.

The problem is when I draw this small image to the big screen I get this...

[image]

The **lines / breaks in pattern are not suppose to be there**. I have tried a lot of things, I thought maybe my atlas was wrong... doubt it. I draw it from (0, 0, 50, 50) which is (x, y, width, height). Checked this a lot and still get the same result, it is as it should be.

Tried different things with my for loop which is below...

```
GL10 gl = this.glGraphics.getGL();
        gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        guiCam.setViewportAndMatrices();

        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);

        // Set background color //

        batcher.beginBatch(Assets.mainmenuAtlas);

        for(int x = Assets.mmbackgroundPattern.width / 2; x < this.scale.getWidth() + Assets.mmbackgroundPattern.width / 2; x += Assets.mmbackgroundPattern.width) {
            for(int y = Assets.mmbackgroundPattern.height / 2; y < this.scale.getHeight() + Assets.mmbackgroundPattern.height / 2; y += Assets.mmbackgroundPattern.height) {
                batcher.drawSprite(x, y, Assets.mmbackgroundPattern.width, Assets.mmbackgroundPattern.height, Assets.mmbackgroundPattern);
            }
        }
```

The viewport & matrices is:

```
public void setViewportAndMatrices() {
        GL10 gl = glGraphics.getGL();
        gl.glViewport(0, 0, glGraphics.getWidth(), glGraphics.getHeight());
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        gl.glOrthof(position.x - frustumWidth * zoom / 2, 
                    position.x + frustumWidth * zoom/ 2, 
                    position.y - frustumHeight * zoom / 2, 
                    position.y + frustumHeight * zoom/ 2, 
                    1, -1);
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
    }
```

When I draw sprites:

```
public void endBatch() {
        vertices.setVertices(verticesBuffer, 0, bufferIndex);
        vertices.bind();
        vertices.draw(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, numSprites * 6);
        vertices.unbind();
    }

    public void drawSprite(float x, float y, float width, float height, TextureRegion region) {
        float halfWidth = width / 2;
        float halfHeight = height / 2;
        float x1 = x - halfWidth;
        float y1 = y - halfHeight;
        float x2 = x + halfWidth;
        float y2 = y + halfHeight;

        verticesBuffer[bufferIndex++] = x1;
        verticesBuffer[bufferIndex++] = y1;
        verticesBuffer[bufferIndex++] = region.u1;
        verticesBuffer[bufferIndex++] = region.v2;

        verticesBuffer[bufferIndex++] = x2;
        verticesBuffer[bufferIndex++] = y1;
        verticesBuffer[bufferIndex++] = region.u2;
        verticesBuffer[bufferIndex++] = region.v2;

        verticesBuffer[bufferIndex++] = x2;
        verticesBuffer[bufferIndex++] = y2;
        verticesBuffer[bufferIndex++] = region.u2;
        verticesBuffer[bufferIndex++] = region.v1;

        verticesBuffer[bufferIndex++] = x1;
        verticesBuffer[bufferIndex++] = y2;
        verticesBuffer[bufferIndex++] = region.u1;
        verticesBuffer[bufferIndex++] = region.v1;

        numSprites++;
    }
```

Here are my texture and texture regions:

```
public TextureRegion(Texture texture, float x, float y, float width, float height) {
        this.u1 = x / texture.width;
        this.v1 = y / texture.height;
        this.u2 = this.u1 + width / texture.width;
        this.v2 = this.v1 + height / texture.height;        
        this.texture = texture;

        this.width = (int) width;
        this.height = (int) height;
    }

public class Texture {
    GLGraphics glGraphics;
    FileIO fileIO;
    Bitmap img;
    String fileName;
    int textureId;
    int minFilter;
    int magFilter;   
    public int width;
    public int height;

    public Texture(GLGame glGame, String fileName) {
        this.glGraphics = glGame.getGLGraphics();
        this.fileIO = glGame.getFileIO();
        this.fileName = fileName;
        try {
            load(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(this.fileIO.readAsset(fileName)));
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public Texture(GLGame glGame, Bitmap img) {
        this.glGraphics = glGame.getGLGraphics();
        this.fileIO = glGame.getFileIO();
        this.img = img;
        load(img);
    }

    private void load(Bitmap bitmap) {
        GL10 gl = glGraphics.getGL();
        int[] textureIds = new int[1];
        gl.glGenTextures(1, textureIds, 0);
        textureId = textureIds[0];

        gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId);
        GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);
        setFilters(GL10.GL_LINEAR, GL10.GL_LINEAR);
        gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
        width = bitmap.getWidth();
        height = bitmap.getHeight();
        bitmap.recycle();
    }

    public void reload() {
        if(fileName.equals(null)) {
            load(this.img);
        } else {
            try {
                load(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(this.fileIO.readAsset(fileName)));
            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        bind();
        setFilters(minFilter, magFilter);        
        glGraphics.getGL().glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    }

    public void setFilters(int minFilter, int magFilter) {
        this.minFilter = minFilter;
        this.magFilter = magFilter;
        GL10 gl = glGraphics.getGL();
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, minFilter);
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, magFilter);
    }    

    public void bind() {
        GL10 gl = glGraphics.getGL();
        gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId);
    }

    public void dispose() {
        GL10 gl = glGraphics.getGL();
        gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId);
        int[] textureIds = { textureId };
        gl.glDeleteTextures(1, textureIds, 0);
    }
}
```

I have tried adding and subtracting from the width added and height added, but makes it look worse.

**My question is what would you look at to try and fix this problem**, I feel very stumped, but **I feel like I may have set something wrong in OPENGL. What could I have setup wrong?**
I can always provide more code up top, but not exactly sure what you may need.

The image I am re pasting over the whole screen is:

[image]

Also the tool I am using to make atlas is [found here](https://github.com/gemurdock/jTextureAtlas) and I am using the one under the beta tree which is considered build 4. However, I checked the atlas over and it seems just fine.

```
public class SpriteBatcher {        
    final float[] verticesBuffer;
    int bufferIndex;
    final Vertices vertices;
    int numSprites;    

    public SpriteBatcher(GLGraphics glGraphics, int maxSprites) {                
        this.verticesBuffer = new float[maxSprites*4*4];        
        this.vertices = new Vertices(glGraphics, maxSprites*4, maxSprites*6, false, true);
        this.bufferIndex = 0;
        this.numSprites = 0;

        short[] indices = new short[maxSprites*6];
        int len = indices.length;
        short j = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 6, j += 4) {
                indices[i + 0] = (short)(j + 0);
                indices[i + 1] = (short)(j + 1);
                indices[i + 2] = (short)(j + 2);
                indices[i + 3] = (short)(j + 2);
                indices[i + 4] = (short)(j + 3);
                indices[i + 5] = (short)(j + 0);
        }
        vertices.setIndices(indices, 0, indices.length);                
    }  

        public void drawSprite(float x, float y, float width, float height, TextureRegion region, boolean corner) {
                if(corner) {
                    float x1 = x;
                    float y1 = y;
                    float x2 = x + width;
                    float y2 = y + height;

                    verticesBuffer[bufferIndex++] = x1;
                    verticesBuffer[bufferIndex++] = y1;
                    verticesBuffer[bufferIndex++] = region.u1;
                    verticesBuffer[bufferIndex++] = region.v2;

                    verticesBuffer[bufferIndex++] = x2;
                    verticesBuffer[bufferIndex++] = y1;
                    verticesBuffer[bufferIndex++] = region.u2;
                    verticesBuffer[bufferIndex++] = region.v2;

                    verticesBuffer[bufferIndex++] = x2;
                    verticesBuffer[bufferIndex++] = y2;
                    verticesBuffer[bufferIndex++] = region.u2;
                    verticesBuffer[bufferIndex++] = region.v1;

                    verticesBuffer[bufferIndex++] = x1;
                    verticesBuffer[bufferIndex++] = y2;
                    verticesBuffer[bufferIndex++] = region.u1;
                    verticesBuffer[bufferIndex++] = region.v1;

                    numSprites++;
                } else {
                    drawSprite(x, y, width, height, region);
                }
            }

    public void present(float deltaTime) {
            GL10 gl = this.glGraphics.getGL();
            gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
            guiCam.setViewportAndMatrices();

            gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);

            // Set background color //

            batcher.beginBatch(Assets.mainmenuAtlas);

            for(float x = 0; x < this.scale.getWidth(); x += Assets.mmbackgroundPattern.width) {
                for(float y = 0; y < this.scale.getHeight(); y += Assets.mmbackgroundPattern.height) {
                    batcher.drawSprite(x, y, Assets.mmbackgroundPattern.width, Assets.mmbackgroundPattern.height, Assets.mmbackgroundPattern, true);


    }
        }
```

Comment: The code reminds me of `libgdx`. There's an overlap of one pixel on the border; I'm unsure whether blending could be an issue.

Comment: @StefanHanke ok, so there is an overlap, how would you go about fixing this? I tried cutting out one less pixel from the atlas... does not work. In fact, makes it worse. Is there something I could do differently? Also I tried blending, but did not seem to help nor hinder.

Comment: The code uses floats, dividing around etc, but finally it will be mapped to integer screen coordinates. Create a `drawSprite` taking int parameters that does not divide.

Comment: @StefanHanke I did what you said, but it did not work. I added the code to the bottom of my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try using GL_NEAREST filtering instead of GL_LINEAR? You may be getting some linear sampling between your edge pixels and the border color.

Specifically here:

```
setFilters(GL10.GL_LINEAR, GL10.GL_LINEAR);
```

Comment: You were correct, THANK YOU SO MUCH! This is the second time you saved me with the same thing! FOR REAL! Where can I learn more about this... I am just beginning open-gl / opengl-es, so is there a book you would suggest or another medium?